# SQL +/- number meaning?

Tags: sql, oracle

I could not find the meaning of the following SQL command:

> where date between to_date('2013-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and trunc(sysdate, 'mm') **-1**

What does the "**-1**" mean / does?

The other example is

> trunc(months_between(date1, date2))**+1**

I have searched for this, but could not find a thing.

Thank you for advice!

Comment: [Date arithmetic is explained in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i48042).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have answered, "date - 1" subtracts one day from the date. Here's more detail on your specific SQL snippets:

```
where date between to_date('2013-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and trunc(sysdate, 'mm') -1`
```

This evaluates to "date between 3/1/2013 and the end of last month"

- `TRUNC(`*some date*, `'MM')` chops the date to the beginning of the month
- `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')` returns the beginning of the current month
- `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')-1` returns the last day of the previous month

---

```
trunc(months_between(date1, date2))+1
```

This is giving the number of full months between `date1` and `date2`, treating any fraction of a month as a whole month. For example, if you gave it the dates `7/28/2013` and `7/29/2013` it would report one month, and it would also report one month if you gave it `7/1/2013` and `7/31/2013`.

The [`MONTHS_BETWEEN` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions094.htm) returns, as it implies, the number of months between two dates. The return value will have decimal places - for example a return value of 1.5 means one and a half months.

The `TRUNC` function, when applied against a numeric, will chop off all its decimals, so `TRUNC(1.9999999)` will return `1`.

Answer (score 2):

`+1` is way to add a day to the date

`-1` is way to remove a day to the date

In your specific case:

the instruction `trunc(sysdate, 'mm') -1` remove one month to the date, in this case is one month before the current date.

the instruction `trunc(months_between(date1, date2))+1` compute the difference in month between the two dates and then adds one.

Give a look at this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/14965)

Answer (score 1):

it is a lazy way of adding or subtracting day(s)

Comment: It's not lazy to avoid reinventing the wheel.